# how to convert url to string in ios/swift?

Tags: ios, swift, url

In my code ios/SWIFT I an trying to read the url from a previous image that I successful saved at Storage Firebase. There is an error at instruction let url1 = url as! String
I need to convert url to string but the cast doesn't work
The print instruction is ok I see the correct url at log screen print(url?.absoluteURL as Any )

```
   let armazenamento = Storage.storage().reference()
    let imagens = armazenamento.child("imagens")
    if let imagemSelecionada=imagem.image {
        if let imagemDados = imagemSelecionada.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.1) {
            imagens.child("\(self.idImagem).jpg").putData(imagemDados, metadata: nil, completion: {(metaDados, erro) in
                if erro == nil {
                    print("Sucess upload")
                    imagens.child("\(self.idImagem).jpg").downloadURL(completion: { (url, erro) in
                        if(erro == nil)
                        {
                            print(url?.absoluteURL as Any )
                            let url1 = url as! String
                            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "selecionarUsuarioSegue", sender: url1)
                        }else{
                            print(err!);
                        }
                    })
```

Comment: *"but the cast doesn't work"* 1) Always copy/paste error and exception output! 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) What language is this, Scala? Please add the language tag.

Comment: What does this have to do with Swing. Swing is a graphical UI for Java. You question has nothing to do with a graphical component. The code posted does not look like Java. Is it JavaScript? (I know JavaScript has a "let" keyword) if so, then using proper tags will give you a better chance of getting an answer.

Comment: The conversion depends strongly on the kind of the URL (remote or local)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to convert url to string use this

```
var myurl: NSURL
var urlString: String = myurl.absoluteString
```

hope it helps

Comment: I have to modify to urlString = (strurl as AnyObject).absoluteString!

Answer (score 3):

yes its easy to do.You can try:

```
var yourURL:NSUL!
var a = yourURL.absoluteString
```

Comment: have you tried ? let url = URL(string: "https://www.zerotoappstore.com/")
let urlString = url.absoluteString

Answer (score 1):

Doesnt' work, but what is the error?

Try not to force-downcast your optionals when not absolutely necessary. Use `if let` optional unwrapping or `guard` 
Anyway, try this -

```
if let strurl = url {
    let urlString = strurl.absoluteString 
    print(type(of: urlString))  // should print "String"
}
else {
    // Your url is nil 
}
```

Comment: I have to modify to; urlString = (strurl as AnyObject).absoluteString!

Answer (score 1):

Go through this link
Here you can find url to string and string to url

https://www.zerotoappstore.com/swift-url-to-string.html

Answer (score 0):

You can convert url to string by using `url.absoluteString`.

```
imagens.child("\(self.idImagem).jpg").downloadURL(completion: { (url, erro) in
                        if(erro == nil)
                        {
                            print(url?.absoluteString)
                            let urlString = url.absoluteString
                            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "selecionarUsuarioSegue", sender: urlString)
                        }else{
                            print(err!);
                        }
                    })
```